# Why does knuths mastermind solving algorithm favour guesses in S?

Tags: algorithm

From [wikipedia : Mastermind > algorithms:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_%28board_game%29#Five-guess_algorithm)

> From the set of guesses with the maximum score select one as the next guess, choosing a member of S whenever possible.

I understand that the hidden code is in S, so it makes sense to choose a guess in S over one that couldn't possibly win in the next turn. But, is this the ONLY reason that this step is necessary? or does it have a more important purpose?

Comment: [Knuth's original paper](http://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~sssousa/RM09101.pdf) says that he worked this out with the aid of a computer but doesn't say where the strategy came from. If I get the chance, I'll ask him about it the next time I see him.

Comment: Thanks. It would be very interesting to know from the man himself.